# How to Cache data independent of IIS

Tags: c#, caching, iis

I have 2 applications Application_A and Application_B. Application_B has caching implemented for Data in Database_B. The cache is on IIS with Application_B.
I need a way through which Application_A will call a WCF service and that web service inturn will call Cache of Application_B but I think that is not possible as Cache is implemented within Application_B.

Is their a way that Application_A can use the Cache using a WCF Service at the same time Application_B can directly use it as internal cache.

Comment: Are Application_A and Application_B web applications? What are they created in? Which ones can you change if needed?

Comment: Are you looking for something like http://memcached.org/?

Comment: @DhwanilShah I can change both but Application_A is preferable. No I am looking something like AppFabric[link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff383731(v=azure.10).aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot recommend AppFabric cache, its for some reason horribly slow for me compared to Redis for example.

But You are on the right path, you might want a distributed cache which runs independently from your apps if you really want to decouple that.

I'd use Redis cache. There is a Windows version of Redis, developed by Microsoft. Also, Microsoft does not offer any other cache on Azure, than Redis for new systems it seems. So that's they way to go!? ;)

If you are scared implementing that on your own or maybe you don't know which cache system to use right now, that's fine. You could use an abstraction layer, like my [CacheManager](https://github.com/MichaCo/CacheManager).

It supports Redis and also AppFabric or Azure cache, although I didn't tested the AppFabric one very well, because AppFabric is bäh...

But you can simply write your application code once and switch the cache system even via configuration if you want...

Comment: Thanks that was the thing I was actually looking for